# CSV import omit a field

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a table from CSV file to phpMyAdmin.
This is my table:

```
1   |Evan|Chigur    |Male|1987-05-25|codefiscale0123|Via Calatafini 17, Palermo, 23451|user@user.it|marco_r|ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee
22  |Hank|Zappasorca|Male|1987-05-25|codefiscale0123|Via Calatafini 17, Palermo, 23451|user@user.it|marco_r|ee11cbb19052e40b07aac0ca060c23ee
```

When i try to fill my table with this, the first field is omitted.
I've already checked out the correspondences of the fields between the cvs and mysql table.

Can anyone help me?

i use this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php7E3C.tmp' REPLACE INTO TABLE `bw_users`FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'ENCLOSED BY '"'ESCAPED BY '\\'LINES TERMINATED BY '*'
```

Comment: could you post a code snippet?

Comment: which is first field? autoincremented id?

Comment: Please share the code you are using to load CSV

Comment: the first field is non autoincremented, it is a sipmle integer

Comment: what is the format of first csv cell?

Comment: you could try explicitly specifying the column names:               LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php7E3C.tmp' REPLACE INTO TABLE (column1, column2, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

how does this work for you?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php7E3C.tmp' REPLACE INTO TABLE bw_users
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

for windows change to

```
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: the first field is '0', for all the records

Comment: in your mysql db, how is the first column defined? quick way to find out: DESCRIBE bw_users